# Php session unset randomly

Tags: php, session

I use a custom session handler which saves and reads session data from the database:

```
class c_session implements SessionHandlerInterface {

    private $db; // Database

    // Constructor
    public function __construct($database){
        $this->db = $database;

        session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, 'open'),
            array($this, 'close'),
            array($this, 'read'),
            array($this, 'write'),
            array($this, 'destroy'),
            array($this, 'gc')
        );
        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    }

    // Custom made session start
    public function start_session() {
        global $globals; // Included in config.php

        // Make sure the session cookie is not accessible via javascript.
        $httponly = true;

        // Force the session to only use cookies, not URL variables.
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

        // Get session cookie parameters and set the parameters
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $globals['https'], $httponly);

        // Change the session name
        session_name($globals['session_name']);

        // Now we can start the session
        session_start();
    }
...
```

In every web page, I read the session to check if the user has signed in:

```
function signin_check($db, $session) {
    global $globals; // Included in config.php
    $session->start_session();
    try {
        // Check if all session variables are set
        if(isset($_SESSION['A'], $_SESSION['B'])) {
...
```

If she hasn't, she is logged out.

Variables *`$_SESSION['A']`* and *`$_SESSION['B']`* are set in the sign in page.

The systems works perfectly 99% of the time, but sometimes, when changing the web page, it logs you out randomly. This happens because both the *`$_SESSION['A']`* and *`$_SESSION['B']`* are unset without a (known) reason.

Why and how can I prevent these log-outs?

Comment: At first glance, it sounds like your sessions time out. If you can check your php.ini settings, can you see what's set for session.cookie_lifetime and session.gc_maxlifetime?

Answer (score 0):

Either the session is timed out, as pointed out by @Rat in his/her comment or there is a code chunk which for some reason unsets `$_SESSION["A"]` or `$_SESSION["b"]`. Check which pages are those where this happens. If you can visit those pages without being logged out, but "sometimes" you are logged out, then there is a problem in your settings. Otherwise you should look into the code of the pages to see where they are logging you out.

Comment: The php.ini settings are the default nginx settings. The only change I made was: session.cookie_httponly = 1, session.cookie_secure = 1. I'm using php-fpm.The problem is not exclusive of some pages and happens sometimes, randomly. I think that it's caused by a race condition.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist what is the value of session.cookie_lifetime and session.gc_maxlifetime?

Comment: session.cookie_lifetime = 0, session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

Comment: @Medicalphysicist can you test logging in now and checking whether you are logged in exactly after two days and one minutes?